# For which fields get snippets created when editing a page layout in SP 2013?

Tags: 2013, page-layout

As mentionend in the topic. When editing a page layout in a given enviroment I'm missing some snippets for fields in design manager, I want to add to the page layout. Maybe there is a mistake in the given page layout or am I missing something? How does SP2013 decide for which fields for which fields snippets get created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snippets are created for all fields of the Content-Type, if you are using site columns and a Site-Content-Type added to the pages-library.